# Unknow option `ngerman' babel

Tags: babel

I'm using LaTeXila on Fedora 19. I switched from MikTeX on Windows to that and I want to work with the files I created there. But every time I compile my `.tex` it gives me the error

```
Package babel Error: Unknow option `ngerman'. Either you misspelled it
or the language definition file ngerman.ldf was not found.
```

I included the language like this

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I got it myself! I just had to reinstall TeXLive and it worked

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was about a faulty installation already corrected by the OP.

Comment: In case its not a faulty installation, try `sudo apt -y install texlive-lang-german`